# Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder:: find()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, unlink

I'm making CRUD, with upload a file (image), but when I want to use unlink to delete the file I got an error, here's below.

Codeigniter4 error: Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder:: find()

This is the codes I used to try to delete the image file. From controller connect to model.

[image]

```
The controller:

    public function delete()
        {
            $model = new Datatablesmodal();
            $id = $this->request->getPost('product_id');
            $model->deleteProduct($id);
            return redirect()->to('/modalboot');
        }
    
    The modal:
    public function deleteProduct($id)
        {
            
            $foto=$this->db->table("formulir_pendaftaran")->find(array('product_id' => $id)); (line 1)
            unlink('/pasfoto/'.$foto['pas_foto']); (line 2)
            $this->db->table('formulir_pendaftaran')->delete(array('product_id' => $id));
            return $query;
        }
```

The id of the table is product_id, if I deleted line 1 and 2 I can delete the data from the table but not the image file it's still in my directory, if I used line 1 and 2 to delete the file I can't because there is an error.

Comment: The error is telling you that the `find` method doesn't exist. I would recommend looking at the CodeIgniter documentation for the proper way to fetch a row.

Answer (score 1):

Exception says that `$db` dosn't have a method called `find()`.

It's because you don't use a Model, you use Query Builder in `$this->db->table()`.

In that way you should use a method `getWhere(array('product_id' => $id))` instead of `find(array('product_id' => $id));`.

But best way to that what you want is creating a Model which corresponds to   table named `formulir_pendaftaran`, and then use this model to delete self.

```
class FormulirPendaftaran extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'formulir_pendaftaran';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    
}
```

and then your model automaticly have a CRUD's method from `Model`, and you could use `delete()` method on that model:

```
$model = new FormulirPendaftaran();
$model->find($id)->delete();
```

and this will delete your instance of $id from Database, but if you want also delete the image you need to extends `delete()` method in your Model:

```
public function delete()
{
    // your code to delete the image.
    parent::delete(); //which delete your instance from DB
}
```